# What is a Commutative Word™?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, word-property, calculation-puzzle

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Commutative Word™**.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{1}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Commutative }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  DAD }&\text{ MOM }\\ \hline
\text{  BIND }&\text{ TIE }\\ \hline
\text{  AXES }&\text{ HOES }\\ \hline
\text{  COVER }&\text{ REVEAL }\\ \hline
\text{  CHINA }&\text{ KOREA }\\ \hline
\text{  FLIRTY }&\text{ CUTESY }\\ \hline
\text{  BOILED }&\text{ FRIED }\\ \hline
\text{  DOUGLAS }&\text{ MATTHEW }\\ \hline
\text{  SESSIONS }&\text{ COOKIES }\\ \hline
\text{  LEGALIZE }&\text{ JUSTIFY }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Commutative Words™,Not Commutative Words™
DAD,MOM
BIND,TIE
AXES,HOES
COVER,REVEAL
CHINA,KOREA
FLIRTY,CUTESY
BOILED,FRIED
DOUGLAS,MATTHEW
SESSIONS,COOKIES
LEGALIZE,JUSTIFY
```

Comment: rot13(V nz gelvat gb svther bhg ubj guvf zvtug or eryngrq gb gur pbzzhgngvir cebcregl ol erneenatvat gur yrggre gb znxr qvssrerag jbeqf, fb sne ab yhpx. Nz V ng yrnfg ba gur evtug genpx?)

Comment: Whenever I see Commutator, I think: Rubik's Cube...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Commutative Word is a word in which

> When converted A1Z26, the multiplication of the first two numbers equals the sum of the rest

Proof:

> DAD -> 4 1 4 -> 4*1 = 4
>  BIND -> 2 9 14 4 -> 2*9 = 14+4 (=18)
>  AXES -> 1 24 5 19 -> 1*24 = 5+19 (=24)
>  COVER -> 3 15 22 5 18 -> 3*15 = 22+5+18 (=45)
>  CHINA  -> 3 8 9 14 1 -> 3*8 = 9+14+1 (=24)
>  FLIRTY -> 6 12 9 18 20 25 -> 6*12 = 9+8+20+25 (=72)
>  BOILED -> 2 15 9 12 5 4 -> 2*15 = 9+12+5+4 (=30)
>  DOUGLAS -> 4 15 21 7 12 1 19 -> 4*15 = 21+7+12+1+19 (=60)
>  SESSIONS -> 19 5 19 19 9 15 14 19 -> 19*5 = 19+19+9+15+14+19 (=95)
>  LEGALIZE -> 12 5 7 1 12 9 26 5 -> 12*5 = 7+1+12+9+26+5 (=60)

Comment: I almost missed it! I thought of it just when you posted it, but I miscalculated twice. Thank god I tried it again :P

Comment: Great Work~~~, and both addition & multiplication are commutative :D

Comment: Yes! Forgot to mention this as the reasoning behind the name :P